# Improve ETL from COBOL file to SQL

Tags: sql, etl

I have a multiserver/multiprocess/multithreaded solution which can parse and extract over 7 million records from a 6gb EBCDIC Cobol file, to 27 SQL tables, all under 20 minutes. The problem; the actual parsing and extracting of the data really only takes about 10 minutes using bulk inserts into staging tables. It then takes almost another 10 minutes to copy the data from the staging tables to their final table. Any ideas on how I can improve the 2nd half of my process? I've tried using In-Memory tables but it blows out the SQL server.

Comment: How you are currently doing the 2nd half of your process? Is it just 23 insert statements?

Comment: So actually what I do is, at the time of setting up the staging tables, I also setup 3 queries per staging table, a procedure which contains the Insert into the final table, second, a Drop Procedure query, and last, a Drop Table query where the target of the drop is the staging table. Also, these queries are queued up so as to be run serially, a necessity because any thread on any machine can be the "final" inserter into the Final table.